# How to get the Previous formula field value in Crystal Report?

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I am creating a crystal report containing the FORMULA fields like Openbalance,debitamount,creditamount and closing balance in details section grouped by its type..

In this, the Previous day Closing balance will be the next day's Opening balance.
Please help me out to get the Previous day Closing Balance which will be in the Open balance field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should be able to get that data from database. right?

Comment: Noo.. Actually the initial open balance data ,debit amount, credit amount are populated  from database.. Other than the Closing balance and the rest Open balance values will be calculated in formula fields..

Comment: can you show sample data on how you are populating

Comment: Sorry ,I dont know how to attach the screen shot of my report here.. but rougly it would be like :                                                 Type -Office  OpenBalance -1000  Debit- 100  Credit -0  CloseBalance -1100.                                                                                                                          This details I have added in detail section of report.. where Open balance,debit and credit amount are taken from database. The Closebalance was calculated from below formula:((Openbalance+Debit)-Credit) in formula field

Comment: Hi Ryan, I tried this.. It works for the database field. But for formula fields, It shows the error like : "A Formula cant represent to itself, directly or indirectly".. I also tried with temporary formula field for passing.. but it too shown the same error. Any Idea to resolve this.

Comment: test the solution provided and let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Shiva. Thank you so much for your idea. Its working great. But small change is needed for my requirement.
I need the opening balance for each record.So I just created inter groups(i.e. first grouped the records by its name and inside,it was grouped by its serial no.,so that i can get values for each record)

Then as you said but without using the counter part.

In the footer section(grouped by Serial No), create a formula field:

```
    Shared Numbervar a;
    a:=//the value you want to pass
```

In the header section(grouped by Serial No),create a formula field:

```
    Shared NumberVar b;
    Shared NumberVar a;
    b:=a;
```

Finally,In the details section formula field,

```
    Shared Numbervar b;
    b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: This is just an idea not the tested solution
```

Its a typical situation but one wayout is try below solution.

1. Group the report according to `Date`.
2. Store the value of the record in a `Shared Variable`.
3. Now use that value when the group changes to a new one and then reset the value to zero.

To spot the first record:

In group header create a formula `@count reset`

```
Shared NumberVar count;
count:=0;
```

Now in detail part increment the count `@Increment` and supress the formula:

```
Shared Numbervar count;
count:=count+1;
```

Now to store last value and show it as the first value follow below process:

Create below formula in group footer `@StoreLast`.

```
Shared Numbervar a;
    a:=// your value that you want to pass.
```

Now create a formulas `@Store Value` and `@reset` in group header as below and place the formula to the left of `@reset`. If the placement changes the result will be zero.

@store Value

```
Shared NumberVar b
Shared NumberVar a;
b:=a;
```

@reset

```
Shared NumberVar a;
a:=0
```

Now place below formula in detail;

```
Shared Numbervar b;

If `{@Increment}`=1
then b
else 
//your code for the rest of values.
```